# web manifesto... forgot the author's name

Tags: design-patterns, web-standards

I don't think it's labeled a "manifesto" but it's basically about how websites should work. One of the things in the list is that it should be accessible via GETs and not POSTs. Have clean extensionless urls, etc... I've seen it linked to a couple of times by bloggers I am just drawing a complete blank on how to find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you perhaps mean some of the articles that written by Tim Berners-Lee and published as part of the [W3C Style Guide](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/)? For example, [this one on extension-less URIs](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI).

[Jakob Nielsen](http://www.useit.com/jakob/)'s [Alertbox](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/) columns are another commonly quoted source. Nielsen is widely acclaimed as somewhat of a user-experience expert before UX was cool. For example, [here is his take on URLs as UI](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990321.html).

Comment: I am pretty sure it was the Jakob Nielsen URLs as UI I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about [Roy Fielding's dissertation on REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)

Comment: Not the specific one I was looking for but this is good too. thanks